# Change link location after visitor's elapsed time on page hits 5 seconds (using PHP)

Tags: php

I am aware that it can easily be done with Javascript and that PHP seems like a bad idea, however I need to do this on my server's side for my project.

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://example.com">Link</a>
```

Change it after 5 seconds to:

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://example2.com">Link</a>
```

Thank you.

edit: Apparently there should be some use of JS. In that case I would like to hide the fact that the links are being changed if someone checks the source code.

Comment: You want to change the link's href after 5 seconds? If so you will need to do using javascript, can't be only server sided.

Comment: This sounds like a really strange idea and it is probably impossible to do this is a precise manner. The only thing you can do on the server side is to _hope_ that the page gets reload after 5 seconds which means you can redeliver it with a modified link inside. That means the 5 seconds cannot be precise. Also the triggering of the reload is questionable: it is either client side javascript again or you have to rely on a meta tag, few browsers actually support this any more...

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible without JavaScript. PHP can affect the HTML only during a request. Your server can't say something like "Hej client, do this!".

So that, you can use JS to change the link or to make another request to your server. Than you can use session to store the last request and compare it to the actual time. If the difference is bigger than 5 seconds, you may change the link.

Answer (score 0):

That's one solution, as you can see it will change the link after 5 seconds trough javascript, but using the link provided by the server script.

```
<?php

$link1= 'http://www.example.com';
$link2= 'http://www.example2.com';
?>
<a href="<?php echo $link1; ?>" id="link1">Click here!</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
    var link = document.getElementById("link1");
    link.href = "<?php echo $link2?>";
    },
    5000); //5000 miliseconds = 5 seconds

</script>
```